# Как изменить цвет Tab'a?

Tags: java, android

Как менять цвет `Tab`, можно-ли назначить как-то background или drawable файл, как для кнопки, только программно?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Только для Android 3.0 и выше.

**res/values/themes.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
  <!-- the theme applied to the application or activity -->
  <style name="CustomActionBarTheme"
       parent="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <item name="android:actionBarStyle">
@style/MyActionBar</item>
  </style>

  <!-- ActionBar styles -->
  <style name="MyActionBar"
       parent="@android:style/Widget.Holo.Light.ActionBar.Solid.Inverse">
    <item name="android:background">@drawable/actionbar_background</item>
  </style>
</resources>
```

После этого ты можешь использовать это с помощью активити-

```
<application android:theme="@style/CustomActionBarTheme" ... />
```

Больше читай тут -https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/actionbar.html#Style